# How can I use updateOne() in PyMongo without adding duplicates?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

any help appreciated (I have read the PyMongo docs and looked at the examples and still can't see where I am going wrong).

I am trying to insert the results of an API request (which receives one or many JSON records) and insert it into my database.

Currently, insert() works absolutely fine as a batch operation, but creates duplicates:

```
mongo.db.arrivalPredictions.insert(predictions)
```

I am trying to make this work in my view, in Flask, and inject through the body of a loop instead:

```
for item in predictions:
    item['rqTimestamp'] = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    item['expectedArrival'] = item['expectedArrival'][11:-1]

    mongo.db.arrivalPredictions.update_one({"id": item['id']}, predictions, { upsert: True })
```

I think I'm close, but right now am receiving a 'NameError: name 'upsert' is not defined' error.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[update_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) in pymongo has `upsert` as a `bool` parameter not a `dict`, so what you need is

```
mongo.db.arrivalPredictions.update_one({"id": item['id']}, predictions, True )
```

or I prefer (as it's a bit more clear):

```
mongo.db.arrivalPredictions.update_one({"id": item['id']}, predictions, upsert=True )
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Only now, I am getting: "pymongo.errors.WriteError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field." ...any thoughts?

Comment: Feels like your `predictions` might be an array - it needs to be a dict.